# Creating a component that is the "mix" of two components (extending from 2 components)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I'm building a set of components which can have variants in their behavior.

More specific, I have a `x-tag` component, which can behave as a `<span>` that simply renders text or an `<a>` that also renders text and links to another route.

For the "link" part I'm using the [link component](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/LinkComponent) provided by Ember (which is the `link-to`) to not reimplement all the routing logic by myself.

**The ideal** would be to only have two components:

- `x-tag`, simple text version that handles the base logic.
- `x-tag-link-to`, link version which should be a component extending from the `link-to` and `x-tag` components.

Since you cannot extend from two components, I moved the logic in the `x-tag` component into a `tag` mixin. So the components ended up like this:

- `x-tag`, compoents that implements the `tag` mixin.
- `x-tag-link-to`, compoents that extends the `link-to` component and also implements the `tag` mixin.

This solves the problem, but is confusing having the logic in several files, also I have a lot more components like the tag that also have a link version, filling the mixins folder with a lot of mixins which have almost the whole component logic. **That just feels wrong**, or is this the right approach?

I can provide code examples if needed.

Comment: Maybe code would be helpful. However consider doing this completely without mixins or extending! Just use composition. Basically have a component for what's inside the span/a, and an outer component with a handlebars if either wrapping the a or the span around it.

Comment: Mixins are right approach to solve these kind of problems.  Also, I usually put mixins for components in `conponents` folder and call them like `tag-mixin`. It seems more logical location to me, as such mixin can be added only to component.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using mixins, as Gennady Dogaev said in a comment.

The result is this:

- `mixins/components/x-tag`: has the tag component logic.
- `components/x-tag`: empty component implementing the mixin.
- `components/x-tag-link-to`: `link-to` component extended to implement the mixin.

---

I discarded composition, although it seems the right path, mapping the implementation of the inside components to the containing component would be a nightmare to mantain in the long run.